# emoji issues or in other words you could say problems

Tags: samsung

On a Samsung Galaxy Exhibit, is there any way to show emojis in text messages or in social media apps?

Answer (score 0):

Diddent quite understand that. But I i
 think I can answer:

What's you android version only 4.0 and higher has emojis.  (go to settings, my device and look at android version) you can get emojis on Android version 4.0 and bellow but you have to be rooted.

If you want to type emojis, download SwiftKey+emoji (free)  from play-store

Answer (score 0):

Emoji are only supported on Android Jelly Bean 4.1 and up. I see that the Exhibit did have an update to Jelly Bean, but not all carriers necessarily provided that. Check your Settings, About, to see if you've got it. If you do, and you're still not seeing emoji, you may wish to try an alternate SMS application, such as GoSMS, to see if they function in that one, as Samsung may not have provided support in their messaging app. If they're still not working even with that, then it's possible Samsung didn't include the emoji functionality in their modified version of Jelly Bean, in which case you're likely SOL without rooting or custom ROMs.